# How to calculate a definite integral with complex numbers involved?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, exponential-function, exponentiation

I'm trying to calculate this integral, and I find it difficult when coping with complex numbers.

$$
f(k) = \int_{lnK}^{\infty} e^{ikx} (e^{x}-K) dx
=(\frac{e^{(ik+1)x}}{ik+1}-K\frac{e^{ikx}}{ik})|_{x=lnK}^{x=\infty}
$$

k is a complex number, Im k>1

and this equation should be equal to 
$$
-\frac{K^{1+ik}}{k^2-ik}
$$
which means the result of the upper limit is 0.

What I cannot understand is that when an infinity multiplied by a complex number, is it still an infinity? It seems like a weird question, and I'm not sure whether I make myself understood. I mean, since exp(-infinity)=0, is exp(a complex number *-infinity) still equals to zero?

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I forget a constraint that k is a complex number, and Im k>1. This time, the upper limit should be well-defined according to my textbook. Actually, it is used to price options..

Comment: I see that $k$ is a complex number, I did not read it correctly, it's OK now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k=\alpha+i\beta$ with $\beta>1$ then
$$\left|e^{(ik+1)x}\right|=\left|e^{i\alpha x}\>e^{(1-\beta) x}\right|=
\bigl|e^{(1-\beta) x}\bigr|\to0\qquad(x\to\infty)\ .$$
 It follows that the improper integral
$$\int_a^\infty e^{(ik+1)x}\>dx:=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^b e^{(ik+1)x}\>dx\tag{1}$$
is convergent, and there is no "multiplication with $\infty$" happening. Just compute the $\int_a^b$ on the RHS of $(1)$  the ordinary way, and you will see that the $\lim_{b\to\infty}$ of this integral exists.

Comment: Thanks, can I interpret in this way: exp(iax)=cos(ax)+isin(ax), so it has a upper bound, and exp(iax)*exp((1-b)x) approaches 0 when x approaches infinity?